# Rails tutorial Chapter 8.2.2 displaying error messages when user enters invalid data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm learning how to register a user using forms on Rails and followed Rails Rutotrial by typing in:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      # Handle a successful save.
    else
      @title = "Sign up"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

BUT, that gave me the following error:

```
Missing template users/create, application/create with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}
```

Note sure why, but when I fixed my code to:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      # Handle a successful save.
    else
      @title = "Sign up"
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

this worked. I'm new to Rails and don't understand why. I put up this post in case there were others out there similarly struggling. But any explanation regarding what's going on would be very much welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You should only be getting that error if your `@user.save` is successful. From your code, what is essentially is happening is

```
if @user.save
  # Handle a successful save
else
  @title = "Sign up"
  render 'new'
end

render 'create'
```

because if you don't tell it to render anything, it will render `views/users/create.html.erb` (aka `/views/{controller}/{action}.html.erb`) and it appears that `views/users/create.html.erb` doesn't exist (note that if you are using HAML, it would be `views/users/create.html.haml`). Maybe you are looking for something like

```
if @user.save
  redirect_to root_path and return
end

@title = "Sign up"
render 'new'
```

That way, if `@user.save` fails to save, it will always render the `new` template, otherwise redirect elsewhere.

Comment: I see. that is very helpful. Indeed, I was wondering why it was insisting on trying to render views/users/create.html. Now that I have render 'new' it works fine. Thanks a ton Axsuul!